# How to make sound work on Mozilla Firefox 52?

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa, mozilla

I use Lubuntu, which I believe does not use pulse-audio, or uses a container for that, I do not know, but it seems to use alsa well.

Since I upgrade to Firefox 52, which does not accept plugins anymore, the sound stopped working, and it shows a tip to fix that, but when I click on it, the site does not exist anymore.

How can I fix the sound on Firefox 52 without replacing alsa?

[image: youtobe requires sound]

[image: tip do not exists]

Comment: A bug has been filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1671273

Comment: And possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/891541/lubuntu-update-no-more-sound-online

Comment: Try [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Videos-sound-pictures-and/tkb-p/Videos-Sounds-Pictures)

Comment: If you don't want to use pulseaudio and stick to ALSA, then use [apulse](https://github.com/i-rinat/apulse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox 52 comes built-in with pulseaudio as default sound output.

So on a system with alsa only, sound is broken on firefox 52.

You can either rebuild firefox 52 with alsa using `--disable-pulseaudio --enable-alsa` as compile option switches.

Or install pulseaudio if you dare!

Comment: AFAIK Lubuntu does use `pulseaudio`. Since there's no point of using ALSA in 2017 anyway, just do `sudo apt install pulseaudio pavucontrol`.

Comment: @dat-tutbrus maybe, sometimes appears PULSE*.log files on my home, I always delete these files.

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections |grep pulse` gives me `libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64` and `libpulse0:amd64` only.

Comment: I will try it in a VM, that is why I didn't answer yet, but even one of these solutions work, they are not what I expected.

Comment: The sound worked on qemu with pulseaudio installed, although I was not what I wanted to do, I am trying to rebuild firefox with alsa, but I cannot get it working, I will wait for Firefox working with alsa.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firefox ESR (Extended Support Release). It still supports plugins.

See https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/ for more information.

See https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/ for downloads.

Comment: unfortunately it is not supported by the official repository, but I have tried the tarball and the result was the same

Comment: @TiagoPimenta but can't you install your desired plugins into ESR?

Comment: I never installed anything to get the sound working, if it was a plugin it was built in. Maybe java works with ESR, but the sound still does not.

Comment: I was hoping that ESR still supported the pulseaudio that you need. Did you install pulseaudio?